# Delete rows with max Date from a table

Tags: date, max, rows, netezza

I need to delete rows from table `table1` when `flag ='N'` and `(current_dt - vl_dt) > 15 yrs`.
While `flag=y` should not delete rows even `(current_dt - vl_dt) > 15 yrs`.
Can any one help on this writing in netezza

> table1
> emp   vl_dt flag
> a 01-01-2020  Y
> a 09-01-2005  N
> a 05-02-2010  N
> b 01-01-2010  N
> b 09-01-2005  N

Comment: emp vl_dt flag
emp1 01-01-2020 Y        emp1 09-01-2005 N        emp1 05-02-2010 N
emp2 01-01-2010 N       emp2 09-01-2005 N

Comment: what's the code you have written, please share

Comment: delete from table1 where emp in ( select emp from table1  A join ( select emp,max(vl_dt) as vl_dt from table1 where flag='N' group by emp)b                                                    using (emp) where A.vl_dt =b.vl_dt and (current_dt-A.vl-dt)/365.25 >15  and A.flag ='N')

Answer (score 0):

delete from table1 where flag = 'N' and current_dt > (vl_dt + interval '15 years');